# How to migrate MySQL,MS SQL to postgreSQL database using jdbc? with java code

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, database-migration

I'm working in postgresql database with jsp/servlets, I need to connect the external jdbc such as MySQL,MS SQL,PostgreSQL and migrate all the datas to my Postgresql database.

Can any one please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Talend DI might help (http://www.talend.com/products/open-studio-di.php) if you need a "one-shot" migration

Comment: [*this*](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) might be helpful

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer i need to migrate using java code...not using third party tool, please let me know if any

Comment: @Sathish Hmm, sorry, not really a duplicate. That question is about converting *dumps*, you want to move data around live using JDBC. I'm not aware of any canned tools to do what you want.

Comment: Do you need to convert the DDL using Java over JDBC too? The `CREATE TABLE` statements, etc? If so, you're going to have a *huge* job ahead of you. If all you need to do is copy *data* between one database and another where the schemas are basically the same, that's a very different and much simpler question.

Comment: previously i was using method as export external database table data to csv and then import it to my postgresql, but here i face an issue when mysql has blob field.im getting only junk values in csv

Comment: i need to push the external table data like mysql,MS SQL tables to my postgresql using java code

Comment: @downvoter can you say y?

Comment: this question is already closed then y downvote, i dono after nearly a year nonsense ******** @downvoter

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no simple solution for your task, unless its a fairly basic project.
In real world sometimes we're forced to use db specific definitions like indices, transaction management, sequences, etc. I'm not telling about db specific queries or things like PL/SQL or Transact SQL that simply are not supported by all the data bases.

If you're using Hibernate/JPA, and in particular schema generation from your entities, you can try to connect to the old schema, fetch all the entities and serialize them on your hard drive, than configure datasource with the new db address and try to deploy the entities there but in general I wouldn't expect that all will be clear and work out of the box

Disclamer, I'm a Java guy, so I share my thoughts from the perspective of java developer and not a DBA :)

Hope this helps

Comment: but i need migrate the external database table datas to my Postgresql database., please let me know if any

Answer (score 0):

This explains [how to connect to PostgreSQL with JDBC](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/). Does that help?

Comment: Its better you do the import and export process manually through java code. could you please modify the question with exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

As RC said in the comments, try using `Talend` they have a `open studio` [Here is the link](http://www.talend.com/products/open-studio-di.php). Free version is absolutely fine with your case. You can write (or design) a job and export it as a jar and use it part of your application or run it as cron scheduler based on your requirement.
They have some tutorials over the web and some on youtube also. They should be helpful.